# Assembly in host store has a different signature than assembly in GAC

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

I have added a third party dll (Extreme.Numerics.Net20.dll to my sql server assemblies). I then opened by VS 2008 project and added that assembly as a reference. Then I built and released my project and it created a PowerstatRegression.dll. Then I add that assembly to SQL Server as well. But when I run my code, I still get this:

```
Error message: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 
'Extreme.Numerics.Net20, Version=3.6.10055.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=9e513770f58567b2' or one of its dependencies. Assembly in host store has a 
different signature than assembly in GAC. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131050) File name: 
'Extreme.Numerics.Net20, Version=3.6.10055.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=9e513770f58567b2' at 
PowerStatRegression.matrix.MatrixHandler.MultiplyMatrixByArray(Double[][] a, Double[] b) at
```

Why is this happening? Everything builds correctly with no errors.

Comment: The SQLCLR maintains its own registry of assemblies independent of the GAC. One reason is if you're trying to load a 32-bit SQLCLR assembly onto a 64-bit SQL Server installation; another can be due to policy redirection (which is a whole animal unto itself); still another can be version mismatches (especially when installing later versions of a DLL for which an original version was never registered in SQL Server.

Comment: I'm doing 32bit assmebly on a 32bit machine. Whay's the policy redirection thing?

Comment: how do i fix a policy mismatch? we had an original version of extreme dll which was a trial, but now i'm pushing one with a license

Comment: Policy redirection is a set of registry entries that are used to intercept calls to a specific version of a .NET assembly and route them to a different version. Without a ton of detail, the SQLCLR doesn't entirely abide the redirections. If you have a later version of an assembly, the simplest thing to do would be to remove any registration about this DLL out of SQL Server, get it clean, then register the new version you want to use.

Comment: you mean just by deleting the assembly from the database right? which i have done many times, or do i have to delete it from the gac?

Comment: I think I'd start as clean as possible with the newest version of the assembly - delete everywhere and start fresh. When you say "When I run my code..." are you talking about a stored procedure in SQL Server that calls your SQLCLR method, or some external program..or?? Just trying to get my mind around the execution context in play here...

Comment: I have a web app that calls a stored procedure that executes the assemblies.  I'll delete it from the GAC and see too.

Answer (score 2):

Change your CREATE ASSEMBLY to ALTER ASSEMBLY and rerun that on the server, that will update the GAC.